# iphone app disable keyboard on UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

Newbie to APP dev, I getting a problem.  When I create my text and then a user taps the text the keyboard comes up, how can I disable the keyboard from coming up?

Can you help me?

Here is my UITextField text code:

```
UITextField *textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(108, 31, 105, 22)];
[contentView addSubview:textField1];
textField1.alpha = 1.0;
textField1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
textField1.text = @"my talent";
textField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
textField1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
textField1.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
textField1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.6 blue:0.6 alpha:1.0];
textField1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
[textField1 release];
```

Comment: Use `UILabel` for read only data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code

```
textField1.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2):

`UITextField` is for entering text, if you just want to show text, use a `UILabel`

Answer (score 2):

you could write on your UIViewController

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return NO;
}
```

but if you just want to show text, you should use UILabel. What do you really want to use it for?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
textField1.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

First set delegate and then use below method

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `textField1.enabled = NO;`